# How to store Twitter ID in Core Data objects

Tags: ios, macos, database-design, core-data, twitter

Any idea what is the best way to store Twitter's tweet ID (and other Twitter data item IDs in general) in a Core Data field? This is to locally cache tweets (and other Twitter data) and will be used as the primary unique ID to link the local data with the one in the server side. That is, any new ID value returned by the API will create a record locally whereas if there is an existing ID in the local data store, the rest of the data will be updated from whatever the Twitter API return. So there will be many fetches done on this field.

This is for the [Core Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data) library for Mac OS X / iOS and the underlying persistent store used is SQLite.

As you might have known, currently [Twitter defines message IDs as 64-bit unsigned integers](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/direct-messages-going-snowflake-on-sep-30-2011). Based on this, I can think of these options store Twitter IDs locally:

1. As a 64-bit signed integer (Core Data doesn't have an unsigned integer type)
2. As a String
3. As a Decimal

Option (1) has two dangers that I can foresee:

- Integer overflows (sign overflow), primarily when parsing the string representation of the ID.
- What if Twitter overflows 64 bit and enlarge their range of ID values?

Option (2) may be less efficient since this field is frequently used in fetches.

Option (3) may not be more efficient than option (2) since [SQLite 3 does not have a native variable-length number type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

The ideal option is probably to store it as 128-bit unsigned integer, which makes them as unique as UUIDs and won't be as large as strings. But unfortunately there is no 128-bit unsigned integer type in SQLite, and anything that's not natively supported in the underlying persistent store can cause problems when using the field as a fetch key.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be a switch from 64 bit to 128 bit (at least not for any good reason like address space), even though it's signed it still leaves you with 63 bits which spans around 9,000,000,000,000,000,000 tweets. Twitter gets 200 million tweets a day. Even if they had a trillion tweets a day it would take 9 million days to overflow. So using 64 bit is certainly safe in that respect.

Comment: +1. By the time you need to worry about overflows there, you'll have plenty more changes to make to your code. I'd go with the integer data type.

Comment: I just looked at how Twitter generates their IDs (the Snowflake schema) and it turns out they're also using only 63-bits, both the most significant 41 bits being a timestamp that should be valid 69 years from 2010. That's a good reassurance for using the signed integer. https://github.com/twitter/snowflake#readme